# Best practices of managing customer orders in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

As I am developing an internal site that allows people from my laboratory to place orders for certain materials through a central database, to keep things manageable.

A person will place an order (can be an item, or multiple items, each with different quantities and etc), and I will log that into the database. However, when I am deciding on how the database would be set up, I am presented with two options:

**Option 1 put all data into one table:**

```
|   Salt   |    Name    |     Email     |   Product ID   | Quantity |Sent|
==========================================================================
|0000000001|John Doe    |john.doe@au.dk |175463          |25        |1   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|0000000001|John Doe    |john.doe@au.dk |300146          |169       |1   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|0000000001|John Doe    |john.doe@au.dk |855457          |5         |1   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|0000000001|John Doe    |john.doe@au.dk |290142          |13        |1   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|0000000002|Jane Doe    |jane.doe@au.dk |173755          |3         |0   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|0000000002|Jane Doe    |jane.doe@au.dk |256984          |39        |0   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Many rows are duplicated increasing read/write/update speed and greatly increasing storage space.  But it is simpler because everything is in one place.

**Option 2:**

Two tables. One that logs an order (and assigns a unique salt). The other logs the order details (the items), and the salt is logged. The salt is not unique in the second table as some orders may contain more than one item. The two databases are linked, as in, when I try to pull out an order, and all the items placed in that order, I will simply search for the salt.

Table 1:

```
|   Salt   |    Name    |     Email     |Sent|
==============================================
|0000000001|John Doe    |john.doe@au.dk |1   |
----------------------------------------------
|0000000002|Jane Doe    |jane.doe@au.dk |0   |
----------------------------------------------
```

Table 2:

```
|   Salt   |   Product ID   | Quantity |
========================================
|0000000001|175463          |25        |
----------------------------------------
|0000000001|300146          |169       |
----------------------------------------
|0000000001|855457          |5         |
----------------------------------------
|0000000001|290142          |13        |
----------------------------------------
|0000000002|173755          |3         |
----------------------------------------
|0000000002|256984          |39        |
----------------------------------------
```

I guess the advantage of the second option is that there is less redundant information in each row - conversely, the advantage of the first is that there is only one table that I have to maintain, compared to two.

Should I use a single table which is easier to take care of initially, or multiple tables to adhere to Database Normalization best practices?  What is the process that you use to decide which way to go?

Comment: I'd rather go on the second design. The table is well normalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked at jobs where a single programmer's pet project has expanded to become tens of thousands of lines of code over the period of a decade (before I was there).  The program, having done everything under the sun, is a mess.  It got to be a mess because of programmers who wanted to do things fast and didn't adhere to timeless coding principles.

So as a specific example of a mess.  There is a database table that has somewhere between 200 and 300 columns.  There is something wrong with it all of the time, and you can't just break it out into a more intuitive structure because that would be a gigantic project.  You are starting the snowball rolling by rationalizing the "cram everything in one place because it is easier" fallacy.

Always make the databases as encapsulated, normalized, efficient and intuitive as possible.  Even if it is harder now, future programmers who have to work on your code will thank you.  Also, if people see you making messes in the code, even trivial projects, you won't be chosen to practice your craft on the spaceships that mines resources from the asteroid belt sometime in next 35 years.  Do a beautiful job because you want to be entrusted with more important things.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer, Eric. So far I have been managing databases for almost a year (since January), and I have to say that I'm starting to figure my way around organizing and storing data. After fiddling around, I realized that the most efficient and direct way is to atomize and normalize tables, such that each row should be unique. Leveraging the power of JOINs has also been one thing that I have learned :)